# Is it possible to enqueue a raw CSS string directly from within a template file?

Tags: css, page-template, wp-enqueue-style

I was wondering if it's possible to enqueue raw CSS as a string directly from within a template file?

I'm writing a custom template for a page and need to add some style rules for it. What I want to do is write the styles out as a string var in PHP then use the enqueue_style function to load these styles, rather than me having to add them in to 'style.css' or some other external style-sheet.

I assumed that so long as I enqueue my styles before calling the 'get_header' function, and if I hook in to the 'wp_head' or 'wp_enqueue_styles' actions, that this would work but it doesn't appear to and I'm not sure if 'wp_enqueue_style' can take a raw CSS string.

Anyone got any advice please?

Kind regards,

Chris

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes and no.

You *can* load a raw CSS string into the header programatically, but you can't use `wp_enqueue_style()` to enqueue it.  That function specifically loads *files* into the header in `<link>` tags.

But what you can do is something like this:

```
function print_inline_script() {
?>
<style type="text/css">
/* ... styles go here ... */
</style>
<?php
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'print_inline_script' );
```

Comment: Great thinkin'.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I just noticed this bit:

> I assumed that so long as I enqueue my styles before calling the
>   'get_header' function, and if I hook in to the 'wp_head' or
>   'wp_enqueue_styles' actions, that this would work but it doesn't
>   appear to and I'm not sure if 'wp_enqueue_style' can take a raw CSS
>   string.

It should be working, make sure you've entered both a handle and a URL for your CSS file.

Comment: Thanks but there is no 'CSS file' I want to enqueue a string variable containing the CSS rules, as I said in the question. Do you know if this is possible?

Comment: as a side note: I believe that it's preferable on here for you to 'edit' your previous answer if you need to change it rather then post a second (unless of course it's an entirely different answer). just fyi

Comment: I'm sorry to welcome you with a downvote, but ***please*** read the full [FAQ](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq) of this site...

Answer (score 1):

As writing styles into templates/plugins directly like `<style>.my-class{...}</style>` is discouraged by the [WordPress Handbook](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/#3-enqueue-stylesheet), and if you have a stylesheet you load anyway using `wp_enqueue_style`, then you may consider using the [wp_add_inline_style()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_style/) function. See the [examples in the docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_style/#user-contributed-notes)` for implementation instructions.

This way you can "hook" your CSS-string onto another stylesheet and it will be displayed as a separate `<style>` element in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as long as it's registered/enqueued before wp_head() in the header.